# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to control raspberry pi camera via c++. I found api (raspicam), installed, checked. It works with an example provided by developer. Now I create my own project and got an error of CMakeLists:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package):
>         By not providing "Findraspicam.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
>         asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "raspicam",
>         but CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "raspicam" with any
>         of the following names:
>
> raspicamConfig.cmake
>       raspicam-config.cmake
>
> Add the installation prefix of "raspicam" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>         "raspicam_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>         "raspicam" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
>         been installed.
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>       See also "/home/pi/raspicam/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

And it is my CmakeLists.txt file:

```
make_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (raspicam_test)
find_package(raspicam REQUIRED)
add_executable (simpletest_raspicam simpletest_raspicam.cpp)
target_link_libraries (simpletest_raspicam ${raspicam_LIBS})
```

I just have started and already got a problem... Could you help please guys? :/

Comment: Your `raspicam` installation should have file `raspicamConfig.cmake` somewhere. Find it, and set `raspicam_DIR` variable to directory where this file is: `cmake -Draspicam_DIR=<dir> ...`. BTW, error message tells exactly that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply! Sorry, I'm new here and don't really know what I do.... So, I found raspicamConfig.cmake (Using comand pwd found it's location /home/pi/Downloads/raspicam-0.1.3/build). Then I just entered this address instead of <dir> in a command you send and clicked enter in terminal. The erroe I have got is "Parse error in command line argument: -Draspicam_DIR /Should be: VAR:Type value /cMake Error: No cmake script provided / CMake error:  Problem processing arguments. Aborting

Comment: Hm, try `cmake -Draspicam_DIR:PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/raspicam-0.1.3 ...` then. At least resort you can modify value of `raspicam_DIR` variable in the `CMakeCache.txt` file under your build directory and run cmake again.

Comment: Just got one more error. Now it says CMake Error: The source directory "/home/pi/raspicam/build/..." is a file, not a directory

Comment: By "..." I mean other options which you pass to cmake(e.g. source directory).

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't really understand what you try to sey. Could you please write a full command I should run . raspicamConfig.cmake is located in /home/pi/Downloads/raspicam-0.1.3/build/. Sorry for desturbing you so much....

Comment: Run `cmake -Draspicam_DIR:PATH=/home/pi/Downloads/raspicam-0.1.3/build <source-dir>` where <source-dir> is directory contained  *your* `CMakeLists.txt`. If you run cmake from source directory, then <source-dir> is just `.`.

Comment: Thanks man! I compiled and now it works :) It was amazing help!

Answer (score 3):

For those who used default instructions in the readme file of the raspicam (as of v 0.1.3, might differ in future):

you can also add

```
set(raspicam_DIR "/usr/local/lib/cmake")
```

to your cmake file before you use

```
find_package(raspicam REQUIRED)
```

That is when you have raspicamConfig.cmake at /usr/local/lib/cmake. If you did not have it at that directory, you can simply search your raspberry to find where it is or you can go to "build" folder in raspicam you used to install before. Then type sudo make install again, which will return "Up-to-date" message along with all a list of files and their locations, including raspicamConfig.cmake. Hope this helps to some.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$ brew install vcpkg
$ vcpkg install raspicam
$ vcpkg integrate install # get path
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/local/Cellar/vcpkg/2021.05.12/libexec/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ..
```