# CMake Error: CMAKE_MODULE_PATH does not contain FindPoppler.cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, poppler

my working platform is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I'm trying to install QCViewer from [github](https://github.com/aparent/QCViewer). It seems a lot of packages are needed from my installation of QCViewer from source. So, I worked on my way through the github repository,  installed all the build dependencies at`/usr`, , and enter the folder `QCViewer/build/release` and run `./build`. This worked fine untill the package "poppler" where cmake gives the following error:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/link/QCViewer-master/build/release# ./build

CMake Error at QCViewer/CMakeLists.txt:63 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindPoppler.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Poppler", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Poppler" with any
  of the following names:

    PopplerConfig.cmake
    poppler-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Poppler" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Poppler_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Poppler" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/link/QCViewer-master/build/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

and also noted that：

`link@ubuntu:~$ pkg-config --libs --cflags poppler
-I/usr/include/poppler -lpoppler`

Meanwhile, I find that this project's `CMakeLists.txt`given as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project(QCViewer)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-2.4 freetype2 poppler-glib)


add_subdirectory(QCViewer)
```

so how can I fix it?

Comment: Looks like the author of the project forgot to add `FindPoppler.cmake` file to the project or use one from ECM. Both ways require modification of the project's `CMakeLists.txt`. If you don't want to do that, just wait responce on [your bugreport](https://github.com/aparent/QCViewer/issues/18).

Comment: Thanks for your help! It took me some time to search similar questions,such as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454649/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt3-find-package) , but I still don't know how to handle my problem,and I guess the author might forgot this project. So I have to resolve it by myself.